# Highcharts: How can I achiveve multiple rows on chart labels?

Tags: highcharts

[image]

How can I achieve something similar to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add another xAxis, linked it to the first one and set appropriate tick interval. Check demo I posted you below.

Code:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  xAxis: [{
    type: 'datetime',
    tickInterval: 3 * 3600 * 1000, // 3 hours
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M', this.value);
      }
    }
  }, {
    offset: 40,
    type: 'datetime',
    linkedTo: 0,
    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
  }],
  series: [{
    data: data
  }]
});
```

**Demo:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/ngp5o98u/

**Api reference:** 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.linkedTo