# How can i create Highchart xAxis labels centered and enclosed?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to replicate the effect on the image but with no luck. On another post someone answered on how to achieve multiple axis lines (see link at the end), but I am unable to achieve the style (labels to maximum width inside the gray and blue boxes).[image: multiline styled axis labels in highchart]

Previous post: [Highcharts: How can I achiveve multiple rows on chart labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53823190/highcharts-how-can-i-achiveve-multiple-rows-on-chart-labels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` to draw `rect` elements, based on the ticks from the second `xAxis` and translate the labels. Please check the example below:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        render: function() {
            var ticks = this.xAxis[1].ticks,
                x = this.plotLeft,
                y = 378,
                width,
                color = 'blue',
                textColor = 'yellow',
                height = 28;

            if (!this.customTicks) {
                this.customTicks = [];
            } else {
                this.customTicks.forEach(function(cTick) {
                    cTick.destroy();
                });
                this.customTicks.length = 0;
            }

            Highcharts.objectEach(ticks, function(tick) {
                if (tick.mark) {

                    width = tick.mark.getBBox().x - x;
                    tick.label.element.children[0].setAttribute('fill', textColor);
                    tick.label.attr({
                        translateX: -width / 2
                    });

                    this.customTicks.push(
                        this.renderer.rect(
                            x,
                            y,
                            width,
                            height
                        ).attr({
                            fill: color
                        }).add()
                    )

                    x = tick.mark.getBBox().x;
                    if (color === 'blue') {
                        color = 'gray';
                        textColor = 'white';
                    } else {
                        color = 'blue';
                        textColor = 'yellow';
                    }
                }

            }, this)

            this.customTicks.push(
                this.renderer.rect(
                    x,
                    y,
                    this.xAxis[1].width + this.plotLeft - x,
                    height
                ).attr({
                    fill: color
                }).add()
            )

        }
    }
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s7vfkgzt/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect

Comment: As expected, an amazing solution from a BlackLabel guy. :). Ill put your code to work, do you mind if I ask you additional questions if I get stuck?

Comment: Just to let you know, if you play a little with the navigator you will see strange effects. Is that related?

Comment: Hi Merak Marey, Of course I will try to help you. Could you describe your problem more accurately? This solution seems to work with navigator.

Comment: Sure, here's a jsfiddle with an example https://jsfiddle.net/sdkb38th/ of a similar behavior in my app. If you want, I can give you access to the end app so you can see the whole picture.

Comment: @Merak Marey, showing the situation on jsfiddle is enough. Please try the code from this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ue3zrn68/

Comment: Sure, this works, but there is still weird issues with the navigator..As example, https://jsfiddle.net/puz3dv8g/ (based on your last jsfiddle, except 2nd axis tick interval is now 60 days)...now, reduce navigator to 50% window using first control, and then drag navigator visible section to the start..

Comment: Hi Merak Marey, Thank you for the example and description of the problem. There was a problem with unsorted ticks, which I solved here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v0krnbpL/ Please check the example and let me know if everything works fine.

Comment: Hi again, I just recently noted that the second row segments don't correspond to the dates on the chart/first axis...so, for example on the last jsfiddle you sent, the 1rst label on the 2nd row say Sep 2018, however, dates on top are from Aug 2018...I'm guessing its somehow related to the `translateX: -width / 2`.., but if I use `translateX: width / 2` making it positive, I will lose the first label..any thoughts?

Comment: Hi @Merak Marey, Yes, you are right. The labels are translated in the wrong direction. Here is the corrected example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lfydhzkg/

Comment: Why is the first dataLabel lost? I can see it rendering...try zooming from the initial slider control and holding it...as soon as you release it the first label dissappears..

Comment: @Merak Marey, Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v0krnbpL The labels are translated to right and the first label is added manually. I improved the logic of adding the first label here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w5s2bmzu/

Comment: Can I ask you one more thing? I want to mod the ticks labels..so, after line 39 of your last jsfiddle I tried soemthing like this..

'for (tInt = 0; tInt < ticksArr.length-1; tInt++) {
   ticksArr[tInt].label.textStr = ticksArr[tInt].label.textStr +' - '+ ticksArr[tInt + 1].label.textStr;
}'
Basically an attempt to concat actual and next label text..but no luck, ...is there a method in the label class to mod the text?

Comment: Hi @Merak Marey, You can use `formatter` function for the labels: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pbqxr5mu/