# How can I add double related x-axis bar to high chart in zoom

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Below is the custom xAxis bar I want to implement.
When user is doing a selection highchart will zoom accordingly and also `datetime` format x-axis would also zoom in & out accordingly.
Which option should I use?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @SkyDev, You can use two datetime x-axis with enabled zoom, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ot6g0fvj/ Filling label backgrounds will be harder to achieve, but this thread should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374921/how-can-i-create-highchart-xaxis-labels-centered-and-enclosed

Comment: @ppotaczek can you submit the answer please? So I can mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two linked datetime x-axis with enabled zoom and different tick interval:

```
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'x'
    },
    xAxis: [{
        type: 'datetime'
    }, {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
        linkedTo: 0
    }]
```

Filling label backgrounds will be harder to achieve, but this thread should help: [How can i create Highchart xAxis labels centered and enclosed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374921/how-can-i-create-highchart-xaxis-labels-centered-and-enclosed)

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ot6g0fvj/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis